# Planning a University Course: Advantages of modern MCU platforms

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, pic, microchip, c++

I want to get sincere advice regarding the use of microcontrollers in educational institutes.
I am an Engineer at a University in India.

We have been using PIC microcontrollers (PIC16 and PIC18) for the Embedded Systems Lab for many years. The labs we cover in the embedded course are interfacing keypads, 7-seg LCDs, CCP (including PWM), ADC, timers, stepper motors,UART and SPI protocols.

I am very confused that should we leave PIC microcontrollers and should use advanced microcontrollers such as ESP32 or STM or anyelse for Electrical Engineering 3rd Semester students…? Or these lab modules on PIC microcontrollers are fine to use for students although they are very old.

Are there objective criteria based on which I can decide whether to redesign the whole course around new hardware, or to keep the established platform?

Comment: [avoid asking subjective questions where … every answer is equally valid](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: If you are programming them in C, then all that people learn will be 98% transferrable to other processors and platforms - understanding how to break a problem down into useful chunks, interfacing at the bit level, debugging. All the little details of the device, the platform, the environment, has to be learned anew when changing between any devices, so it's impossible to pick one device that will set them up for the indefinite future.

Comment: I've voted to close, on account of this being a subjective question.  Nevertheless: in my opinion the best thing you could do is teach any two processors.  With two, the similarities and differences are readily apparent.  And having said that, I don't think there's anything wrong with teaching with PIC, ATMega, STM.  I also think one of the most important things is that students learn "the whole thing": with the smaller processors you stand a chance of understanding it all; with the larger processors there is simply too much to cover.

Comment: My university used a silicon labs C8051 you can teach simple assembly and also have GPIO. Other than that you could use an industry standard. It might be good to go with a widely accepted chip such as an STM32

Comment: I had a longish answer prepped, but it looks like it got lost when the question got closed (I placed a reopen vote).  My advice is to pay very close attention to the *whole toolchain*, and think long and hard about how you intend to support that toolchain with inexperienced students.

Comment: @ScottSeidman I'd also recommend starting by actually writing down what you want to teach. For example, I find that if you teach based on PIC16, you're kind of bound to a strange vendor IDE, that feels like it's from the 90s (guess why), and your students might be quite busy with learning "quirks" of that IDE and how to deal with low-level special aspects of your microcontroller, whereas if you start them with say ESP32, you can use the same IDE they want to use, the same modern C (C11, C23) or even C++ that they've learned in their programming course, and you can focus on a less "hardware-

Comment: specific" view on embedded computing. I bet your goal is not to teach them how to program one microcontroller family (say, PIC16/PIC18 or STM32F0) really well, but to teach them what an interrupt service routine is, in general, what a PWM unit is, in general, and to give them a bit experience in applying that e.g. to build a simple PID controller. That might be significantly easier on a "mightier" platform. And: an ESP32 C3 devkit costs ₹670 and can be directly connected to a PC, contains the programmer and everything necessary to build a small device out of it. And it does things the students

Comment: might find very attractive – Wifi, bluetooth – so that they would be motivated to learn the platform and actually build something extracurricularly. I'd honestly probably settle on the STM32G0 platform, which is not quite as feauture-rich (and thus complicated) as an ESP32 but also not making design choices of the late 1990s (that's 23 years ago! An eternity in modern electronics, to be honest) like PIC18 or 1980s (few of your students parents will have been in studying age at that point! So old!) like early PIC16.

Comment: Students need a path for debugging and aids for troubleshooting. Consider if a simulator or emulator is available including breakpoints, and can single-step instructions. Good development tools are more important than choice of embedded family types.

Comment: What @glen_geek said. Debugging interfaces in modern e.g. ARM Cortex-M processors are *way* better than what I used to use with e.g. Atmel processors. Don't know about PICs, to be honest.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - the first sentence of the dead Ling answer was "it depends on what you're trying to teach".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you are on the correct track, stay with the existing hardware, this will give them the basics with a tremendous amount of resource material available for them. The next step would be for a single core microprocessor such as the Z80, 6800, 6502 etc,which needs external memory. With this they will learn I/O addressing, memory addressing, what boot loaders do, and all the stuff hidden from in the arduino that will be important in future designs. Then go to something with several cores such as an ESP devices. After that go into something like the PC or whatever, but this will take several semesters to go through if taught properly and the students learn what is happening.

Comment: I mean, that'd be kind of cool if a) you really *want* to teach people about computing history (you don't need to go for historical examples just to illustrate simple processors. A simulated processor like a picorv32 would totally do, and if you want it to light actual LEDs there's modern 8 bitters&FPGAs that you can buy) b) have really something you need to teach them about memory buses at that level and c) have **a lot** of time. If that embedded course *also* has the job of building something functional (and using an MCU instead of MPUs indicates that), then you'll not have sufficient time.

Comment: I find that as someone who teaches, we often take the approach of "I learned it this way, because I was taught it in this order, because when I was learning it, things were still unraveling, so the new things were advanced and taught later on": I find this is rarely a good approach for technical stuff. Sure, I can start a course in communications engineering in 2023 with AM, FM, then come to asynchronous FSK, then start introducing coherent receivers, and digitizers, and finally do PSK. But if the course is really supposed to teach them something useful in 2023, scratch all the historically

Comment: relevant but research&development-irrelevant stuff like AM and FM (or leave it as a later footnote). Same for embedded computing: Nobody needs to have heard of the Z80 to write good microcontroller code, seriously. Why would you want to teach about external memory buses in an entry-level course? That simply doesn't happen on small MCUs these days,and even if it does,the hardware is there to abstract your memory accesses. It really doesn't help. You can abstract, and simplify, without going back to the devices where a lot of things were still unnecessarily complicated and not abstracted at all!

Comment: Z80, 6800, 6502 etc. can be useful for teaching computer architecture. They are pretty useless for teaching microcontroller programming.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're trying to teach your students.  I teach an engineering design course.  I also teach an online course on Interfacing with Microcontrollers.

In the latter, the focus isn't really on programming the microcontroller, it's more about what you're doing with the pins you can see.  I use an Arduino for this, because I'm not teaching programming, and the environment is multiplatform and bulletproof.  There's a ton of community support students can go to for that stuff.  If a student says "my environment doesn't work" my interaction is to tell the student to close it and reopen it, reboot, or reinstall.  Never had a problem.

If I were teaching a programming course, it would be a completely different story.  My own opinion is that the Arduino IDE hides many of the things I'd want students to understand.  I like the 8-bit PICs for that, but with a commercial compiler -- but honestly, I haven't taught a course around that.  I have taught many students one or two on one, though.  I would also look hard at some of the STM ARM Cortex 4 eval boards, because of the power and price point, but there are some toolchain issues I'd need to sort through.